# 「どこまで行くんだい？」 「どこまで行くんかい？」

Tags: word-choice, questions, sentence-final-particles

Since だい usually follows sentences with an interrogative word, and かい occurs in polar questions, I thought this would be the most natural wording:

> どこまで行くん(の)だい？

But apparently どこまで行くん(の)かい is also attested:

> この先行きどまりだよ。どこまで行くんかい？([source](https://yamap.com/activities/15301139/article))

> 「どこまで行くんかい？」
> 「ハイ、近くを散策します」([source](https://yamap.com/activities/10738453))

> どこまで行くのかい？疲れた足取りで平気な顔して無理してるんだろう([source](https://j-lyric.net/artist/a0518ca/l0207ce.html))

Any difference at all in meaning and usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usage is uncommon and I'm not familiar with this. It sounds dialectal, but I can associate this with no particular dialect.

どこまで行くんかいな or どこまで行くんかいの is at least more common than this (sounds like 昔話). どこまで行くんですかい is commonly used in fiction (typically by hoodlum-type characters). 何かい is also common (sounds like 江戸弁 in rakugo) but this is probably a fixed phrase.